# Printing the results of the method find_simple_stmt_nodes (Module Db.Pdg)

Tags: frama-c

How could i print the results of this function **find_simple_stmt_nodes : (t -> Cil_types.stmt -> PdgTypes.Node.t list) Pervasives.ref**.Is there a method to do that? If anybody could help me... I tried something like that:

```
let listeStatement= !Db.Pdg.find_simple_stmt_nodes pdg assert_stmt in

let rec print_list = function

   [] -> ()

   | x :: l -> Format.printf "%a@." (!Db.Pdg.pretty_node false) x; 

   print_string " "; Format.printf "%a@." (!Db.Pdg.pretty_node false) l  in

   print_list listeStatement;;
```

Comment: This is not a Frama-C problem, it is an OCaml one. ``x`` is a node, but ``l`` is a list of node. You should learn how to print a list in OCaml first.

Comment: You are right!  I did not understand! I followed an example stupidly! Sorry

Comment: Note that there is a function `Pretty_utils.pp_list` to print lists, but it uses advanced OCaml features.

Comment: Thank you Boris! I am going to do researches about that